# Cloud Dataprep - Replace code or id with value with middle dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep, trifacta

I'm really new in GCP dataprep and now trying to create a recipe, but I can't figured out the way of doing it.

In summary I have 2 files, the first one with this columns:
*NAME, CONTRY_CODE,* ...

And the second one with:
*COUNTRY_CODE, COUNTRY_NAME*

How do I replace the *COUNTRY_CODE* from the first dataset with the *COUNTRY_NAME* of the second one (matching with the corresponding *COUNTRY_CODE*)?.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to make this type of things. You can achieve it with the **Lookup** property in Dataprep!.

Just select the column you want to change (in my case *COUNTRY_CODE*), then select *Lookup* -> Pick a Dataset (in my case the second one). And it will replace it as expected!

Answer (score 0):

While the Lookup answer will work correctly, the `JOIN` option may be a better solution for for extensiblity as it supports multiple columns on the remote side, shows you the match rate, allows fuzzy matching, and lots of other goodies (like ignoring whitespace in the matches).  You can also choose the join type to control how output and missing rows are handled.

Semantically these two options aren't much different and I haven't seen a real performance difference—but I've been able to simplify some of those operations by using a Join like this:

[image: Google Cloud DataPrep step menu showing a simple Join operation]